# Как найти ближайший к дате будущий понедельник?

Tags: java, дата

Чувствую, что Java 8 это умеет, но пока не могу найти

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-) класса [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html):

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate nextMonday = currentDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
```

Также может быть полезен метод [`nextOrSame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-), поведение которого отличается если текущая дата уже является понедельником.

Comment: exactly!!!!!!!! опередил)